# Block With Given ID Does Not Exist - Minecraft Mod

Tags: java, minecraft-modding, modding

I have tried to make my own Minecraft Block using `Forge`, but for some reason, when I use `/give Playerxxx 1000 1` the game says, `There is no block with id '1000'`

My Block Code:

```
package net.minecraft.blockr;

import net.minecraft.block.Block;
import net.minecraft.block.material.Material;
import net.minecraft.creativetab.CreativeTabs;

public class Basalt extends Block
{
    public Basalt(int par1, Material par2Material)
    {
        super(par1, par2Material);
        this.setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.tabBlock);
    }

}
```

Mod code:

```
package net.minecraft.blockr;

import cpw.mods.fml.common.Mod;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.Mod.Init;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.network.NetworkMod;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.registry.GameRegistry;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.registry.LanguageRegistry;
import net.minecraft.block.Block;
import net.minecraft.block.material.Material;


@Mod(modid="blockr", name="Blockr Mod", version="PreAlpha v0.0.1")
@NetworkMod(clientSideRequired=true, serverSideRequired=false)
public class BlockrMod
{
    public static Block basalt;

    @Init
    public void load() 
    {
        basalt = new Basalt(1000, Material.ground).setUnlocalizedName("basalt");

        GameRegistry.registerBlock(basalt, basalt.getUnlocalizedName());
        LanguageRegistry.addName(basalt, "Basalt Block");
    }

    public String getVersion()
    {
        return "0.0.1";
    }
}
```

What exactly is going wrong?
My package is `blockr` (as my mod is called blockr)

I know my mod was loaded as I see in `Forge` under `Mods` I see my mod

Comment: You're gonna get a bunch more help on the Minecraft or Forge forms. I recommend you read [this page](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/about) before posting again.

Comment: If I recall correctly 255 is the highest possible block ID, but that was when I modded all the way back in 1.2.5 and earlier. Try a lower number perhaps

Comment: @TheNickmaster21 While he will likely get more help on those forums, the page you linked has little to do with that, and the [consensus on meta](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/58/do-mod-and-map-making-questions-belong-here) is that modding questions can be on topic here.